# Selection sort without repetition

Tags: selection-sort

I have to implement a variation of selection sort algorithm.
In this variation, the algorithm must remove the duplicated numbers.

I managed to do that by sorting the vector and then removing the repeated elements in a follow up loop.

I guess there is another more efficient way to do this job, but I can't think of anything.
Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency differences will be marginal, since you're intentionally using a quadratic-time algorithm for something that we know can be done faster.  The difference between n<sup>2</sup> and n<sup>2</sup> + n is pretty unimportant, after a certain point, since it's essentially n * (n + 1).

With that caveat, the selection sort is in a category we call "comparison sorts," because the decisions of placement are made based on pairwise comparison.  Non-comparison sorts are those like counting sorts:  How many of each object have we found?  We don't care about any other elements than the one we're looking at right now.

So, because you need to compare the magnitude of each pair of elements anyway, you should already know if you have a duplicate at that time.

That might not be the entire story, though.  How you manage those duplicate values could easily take more time than that one loop, if not handled carefully.